# keydown event reusable code - how can I write it once and use anywhere in my flex application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, conventions

I am new to flex framework.

I have created an application using flex framework 4.1 which is having various components that are shown to the end user in the form of a popup window using `<mx:TitleWindow>`.

This titlewindow is closed either on the click of the close button (displayed in it's titlebar) or by pressing the "escape key" on the keyboard.

I coded a functionality wherein I close the current TitleWindow whenever an 'escape' button is pressed.
Here is what I did.
On the `keydown` event of `TitleWindow` I called this function

```
private function detectescapekeypress(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(event.charCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE)
       PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
}
```

But this function does not work when I define it in the main home screen of my application and call it using `parentApplication.detectescapekeypress(event)` on the `keydown` event of `TitleWindow`

I had to repeat this code for every TitleWindow that I have used in the project.

How can I write the above functionality only once and reuse it amongst various TitleWindow and other components so that the code for the same is not repeated across various components?

Note: Every TitleWindow that I am using has different code, scripts and layout in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't u just extend the TitleWindow component and add that functionality to your new custom component? Then use it everywhere instead of the original TitleWindow.

I assume u're using at least SDK 4.1
Create a new mxml file called for example CustomTitleWindow.mxml and paste the following
http://www.copypastecode.com/68211/

Then change all your title windows to CustomTitleWindow.

P.S. Note that in order for the key event to be dispatched, the component must have focus.

blz

Comment: @Anton Petrov: Thanks for your suggestion, can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: You can put it in a new folder called "view" in your src folder for example. Then you should include a namespace in the component you want to use it in:
in the root tag: xmlns:view="view.*"
then just use <view:CustomTitleWindow>

If you're using Flash Builder, it will be automatically added for you when you try to autocomplete <CustomTitleWindow

Comment: not working as I wanted it to. I wanted to remove the repetition for same functionality and not the component itself. The titlewindow in every case is having different layout, scripts and code inside it. How come that be achieved, I doubt it. :(

Comment: You can use your custom component the same way you use the TitleWindow. Just include the common functionality in your CustomTitleWindow and then, if you want more different customized functionality, just keep extending the component. Or you can try setting some properties, states to it and etc.
If i still haven't understood, please give me a more detailed and specific explanation of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: okay here it is. I created the component in the components directory. wrote the code for the titlewindow in it. THen i tried to call that customcomponent in another component (which will actually be a popup). Now where shall I enter my code for GUI display and actionscript code after writing <components:CustomTitleWindow width="300" title="registration"></components:CustomTitleWindow>

Comment: You can create a RegisterPanelPopUp.mxml and extend CustomTitleWindow in it, just like you did with TitleWindow. You can then add new components with MXML and also include a Script block and do whatever you want with ActionScript.

Another way is to just add children to the mxml tag:
<components:CustomTitleWindow width="300" title="registration">
  <s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout />
  </s:layout>
   ...
  <s:Button id="registerButton" />

</components:CustomTitleWindow>

Comment: :) thanks for your kind attention and quick help. I got it now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Understood but Not working.. something's wrong. Can you please have a look at it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593796/how-do-i-call-a-customcomponent-with-added-functionality-in-flex