# how do I call a customcomponent with added functionality in flex

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, code-reuse, custom-component, reusability

I have created a custom component (named customtitlewindow) the code of which is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" layout="vertical" width="400" height="300"
                xmlns:comp="components.*"
                showCloseButton="true"
                keyDown="detectescapekeypress(event)"
                creationComplete="this.setFocus();"
                close="PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);"
                paddingTop="40">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
            public function detectescapekeypress(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                if(event.charCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE)
                {
                    PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Now I again created a component (named deleteconfirm) which calls the above one like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Container xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300" xmlns:components="components.*">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <components:customtitlewindow title="custom title window">
        <s:Label>
            <s:text>this is the custom text for deleteconfirm.</s:text>
        </s:Label>
        <s:Button label="ok">
            <s:click>
                <![CDATA[
                    Alert.show("Hello world!", "title");
                ]]>
            </s:click>
        </s:Button>
    </components:customtitlewindow>
</mx:Container>
```

(in main file) Now on the click of a button I am calling the above (second one) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
  <mx:Script>
     <![CDATA[
           import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
       ]]>
  </mx:Script>
  <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
     <mx:Button label="Delete Record">
         <mx:click>
             <![CDATA[
                var ctd:deleteconfirm = new deleteconfirm();
                ctd = deleteconfirm(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, deleteconfirm, true));
             ]]>
         </mx:click>
     </mx:Button>
  </mx:VBox>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

The main purpose of mine is that for all the popup windows shown to end user all of them be closed when the escape key is pressed and all of them be closed upon click of the closebutton displayed at the titlebar.

But on the "escape key" press nothing is happening.
How can I do this?
What is wrong? Please correct me where ever I am wrong above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this for your deleteconfirm class:

```
<components:customtitlewindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300" xmlns:components="components.*" title="custom title window">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

        <s:Label>
            <s:text>this is the custom text for deleteconfirm.</s:text>
        </s:Label>
        <s:Button label="ok">
            <s:click>
                <![CDATA[
                    Alert.show("Hello world!", "title");
                ]]>
            </s:click>
        </s:Button>
</components:customtitlewindow>
```

Also, you should look into adhering to proper standards like uppercasing on classes (instead of deleteconfirm, it should be DeleteConfirm; and it wouldn't hurt to be more descriptive).

Comment: +1 for adhering to uppercasing standards and descriptive naming. :)

Comment: I get this error when I clicked on the delete button : "Multiple sets of visual children have been specified for this component (base component definition and derived component definition)." Googled about this and I think it is not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: try doing this instead: `<s:Button label="ok" click="Alert.show('Hello world!', 'title')" />`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to remove the wrong popUp reference.

The popUp that you are creating is an instance of the *deleteconfirm* class but when you try to remove it, on the *detectescapekeypress()* function, you are passing an instance from a *customtitlewindow* class.

An **easy way** to fix it is by changing this line in the *detectescapekeypress()*:

```
PopUpManager.removePopUp(IFlexDisplayObject(this.parent));
```

**The best** way to fix it, would be to move the key-press handling to the *deleteconfirm* class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think your solution would defeat the purpose of my question. I don't want to repeat the code for escapekeysequence.